# Привязка контента к всплывающей подсказке ToolTip WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Пытаюсь в приложении организовать всплывающие подсказки. Не пойму как сделать привязку значения поля к ToolTip Content. В Разметке делаю таким образом (в тегах ToolTip код скопипастил, он выдает содержимое контрола):

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ToggleWebServiceCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="24" Width="90" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="214,9,213,7" >

        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <!-- Triggered values -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStreaming}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Стоп"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStreaming}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Старт"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,
                        RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

Ну и во ViewModel создал readonly поля (не знаю как все-таки верно в MVVM правильно делать, возможно лучше свойство с  OnPropertyChanged();)

```
 /// <summary>
    /// For main xaml Take a photo tooltip message
    /// </summary>
    public readonly string getPhoto = "Нажмите, что бы сделать фотографию";
```

Вроде бы ничего сложно, но просто байндить контент не вышло.

Comment: `Ну и во ViewModel создал readonly поля` - Binding к полям невозможен! Используйте свойства.

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало!

Comment: ' public string GetStarted { get; } = "Нажмите для запуска";'